# Can rosbag record only some fields from a topic?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do so, but when I try to play back, rosbag shows this error:

```
[FATAL] [1338427215.385261009]: Time is out of dual 32-bit range
```

This happens regardless how long I record data. When recording the whole topic all goes fine.

I have tried to record both the desired fields and the topic time stamp, but I get the same error.

Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35293/can-rosbag-record-only-some-fields-from-a-topic?/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-30**:
Can you show the parameters you used for rosbag?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2012-05-31**:
nothing special; just "rosbag record /"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosbag can only record full topics, not only some fields from a topic. However, if for some reason you want to omit some fields from a recorded bag file, you can use rosbag's [Code API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API), which is pretty amazing. It should take less than 10 lines of code to filter a "full" bag file, drop some fields, and write the result a second (reduced) bag file.

> when I try to play back, rosbag shows this error:
> [FATAL] [1338427215.385261009]: Time is out of dual 32-bit range

Yes, that error message is not very intuitive. :-)

What's happening is this: When you do, say:

```
rosbag record /scan/ranges
```

... rosbag thinks that you want to record the **topic** `/scan/ranges`, but that doesn't exist ("ranges" is a field of topic "scan"). That means that your resulting rosbag will be *empty*, and that is what the error message really means. It's misleading though, and I filed a bug report [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3976).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2012-06-10**:
Thank you a lot, that makes all clear now. What I did is to record the whole bag and the filter the fields I need with rostopic.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bug which caused that weird error message has been fixed. The update will be included in ros-comm 1.8.14. Then you will see a reasonable message like "No messages to play".

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-07-03**:
Great, thank you!